# In jupyter notebook 'Run' & 'Kernel' options are disabled

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-kernel

I'm new to Python programming. I just downloaded a python project code to test train the sample.

Has installed python & jupyter notebook desktop setup in windows 10, but in both the localhost web environment & desktop setup I'm unable to RUN any of the scripts cause all the submenu options of 'Run' & 'Kernel' are disabled.

All those experts in the stack overflow are requested to pls guide in further.

Comment: Are they disabled in notebooks or in file editor? In order to run scripts via file editor you need to use context menu → "create console for editor" but this may change soon: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12172

Comment: for new users, i recommend `vs code` as an editor. This editor lets you run both python files `*.py` and jupyter notebook files `*.ipynb`...

Comment: @krassowski okay I did that but it creates console with blank cells it has got nothing to run. The python code file doesn't run.

Comment: Earlier I had created an virtualenv using cmd prompt command does it has anything to do with interpreter?.

Comment: Once you have console open (with a kernel selected) you can select the code in editor and press `shift` + `enter`.

Comment: Actually after creating first python notebook all the options has been made available. May be executable environments where not created.